# Can Win32 "move" heap-allocated memory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a .NET/native C++ application.  Currently, the C++ code allocates memory on the default heap which persists for the life of the application.  Basically, functions/commands are executed in the C++ which results in allocation/modification of the current persistent memory.  I am investigating an approach for cancelling one of these functions/commands mid-execution.  We have hundreds of these commands, and many are very complicated (legacy) code.

The brute-force approach that I am trying to avoid is modifying each and every command/function to check for the cancellation and do all the appropriate clean-up (freeing heap memory).  I am investigating a multi-threaded approach in which an additional thread receives the cancellation request and terminates the command-execution thread.  I would want all dynamic memory to be allocated on a "private heap" using `HeapCreate()` (Win32).  This way, the private heap could be destroyed by the thread handling the cancellation request.  However, if the command runs to completion, I need the dynamic memory to persist.  In this case, I would like to do the logical equivalent of "moving" the private heap memory to the default/process heap without incurring the cost of an actual copy.  Is this in any way possible?  Does this even make sense?

Alternatively, I recognize that I could just have a new private heap for every command/function execution (each will be a new thread).  The private heap could be destroyed if the command is cancelled, or it would survive if the command completes.  Is there any problem with the *number* of heaps growing indefinitely?  I know there is some overhead involved with each heap.  What limitations might I run into?

I am running on Windows 7 64-bit with 8GB RAM (consider this the target platform).  The application I am working with is about 1 million SLOC (half C++, half C#).  I am looking for any experience/suggestions with private heap management, or just alternatives to my solution.

Comment: Are you asking if the memory you allocate in one heap can be "reassigned" to another heap without actually copying the data?

Comment: I'm 92% sure the answer is no.  But not enough to post it as an answer.

Comment: Heap memory allocation isn't the only problem you'll have with forcibly terminating threads. The only safe way to terminate a thread is from the inside. That way, you know the thread isn't in the middle of some locked operation. Interruptibility needs to be an intrinsic feature of your functions; it's not something you can bolt on from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap is a sort of big chunk of memory. It is a user-level memory manager. A heap is created by lower-level system memory calls (e.g., `sbrk` in Linux and `VirtualAlloc` in Windows). In a a heap, then you can request or return a small chunk of memory by malloc/new/free/delete. By default, a process has a single heap (unlike stack, all threads share a heap). But, you can have many heaps.

- **Is it possible to combine two heaps w/o copying?** A heap is essentially a data structure that maintains a list of used and freed memory chunks. So, a heap should have a sort of bookkeeping data called meta data. Of course, this meta data is per heap. AFAIK, no heap manager supports a merge operation of two heaps. I had reviewed entire source code of malloc implementation in Linux glibc ([Doug Lea's implementation](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c)), but no such operation. Windows Heap* functions are also implemented in a similar way. **So, it is currently impossible to move or merge two separate heaps.**
- **Is it possible to have many heaps?** I don't think there should be a big problem to have many heaps. As I said before, a heap is just a data structure that keeps used/freed memory chunks. So, there should be some amount of overhead. But, it's not that severe. When you look at one of [malloc implementation](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c), there is `malloc_state`, which is a basic data structure for each heap. For example, you can create another heap by `create_mspace` (in Windows, it is `HeapCreate`), then you will get a new malloc state. It's not that big. So, if this tread-off (some heap overhead vs. implementation easiness) is fine, then you may go on.

If I were you, I'll try the way you describe. It makes sense to me. Having a lot of heap objects would not make a big overhead.

Also, it should be noted that technically moving memory regions is impossible. Pointers that pointed the moved memory region will result in dangling pointers.

p.s. Your problem seems like a transaction, especially Software Transactional Memory. A typical implementation of STM buffers pending memory writes, and then commits to the real system memory it the transaction had no conflict.

Comment: @STingRaySC: Mapping between virtual address and physical address is nothing to do with this problem. We just can't see such mapping. We're only considering the move/merge in virtual address space. Programmers can only see virtual address (except some embeeded or real-mode situations). Yes, mapping to physical address can be always changed, but this is completely hidden. However, moving/merging b/w heaps is done within only virtual address spaces, so, it is generally impossible unless we implement very expensive mechanism to track down referenced pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You might be better off with separate processes instead of separate threads:

- use memory mapped files (ie not a file at all - just cross-processed shared memory)
- killing a process is 'cleaner' than killing a thread
- I *think* you can have the shared memory 'survive' the killing without a move - you map/unmap instead of move

although you might need to do some memory management on your own.

Anyhow, worth looking into.  I was looking into using inter-process memory for a few other things, and it had some unusual properties (can recall all of it clearly, it was a while ago), and you might be able to take advantage of it.

Just an idea!

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN's [Heap Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366711(VS.85).aspx) page: 
"Memory allocated by HeapAlloc is not movable. The address returned by HeapAlloc is valid until the memory block is freed or reallocated; the memory block does not need to be locked."

Can you re-link the legacy apps against your own malloc() implementation?  If so, you should be able to manage without modifying the rest of the code.  Your custom malloc library can track allocated blocks by thread, and have a "FreeAllByThreadId() function which you call after killing the legacy function's thread.   You could use private heaps inside the library.

An alternative to private heaps might be doing your own allocation from memory-mapped files.   See "[Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx)."   You create the shared memory while initializing the alloc library for the legacy thread.  On success, map it into the main thread so your c# can access it; on termination, close it and it is released to the system.

Answer (score 1):

No. Memory cannot be moved between heaps.